# Ubuntu taking time to install

Tags: system-installation

For the past three hours, Ubuntu's installation is hanging at this spot:

[image: This is the problem]

Is there anything I can do to resume the install?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to add a commend but can you hit the little arrow > beside the word installing system and see if it drops down to see where its at in the installer? As there is very little info to work with based on your image.

Comment: Before "installing system" is an > Click it to see notices.

Comment: Xorg is not installing

Comment: Please help I iam noon in Linux

Answer (score 0):

Firstly download the Ubuntu ISO from the Ubuntu official website (it is free). Then go and find the UNetBootin app for installation on all platforms. Then make your USB bootable from the Other computer and try re installing Ubuntu.

I hope this works for you!